Как сделать следование части скелета за GameObject в Unity?
Есть модель водоплавающего со скелетом, которая анимирована (небольшие движения вверх-вниз). Она находится в родительском GameObject, через который осуществляется перемещение по точкам, точки переключаются по соприкосновению коллизии в этом GameObject'е c триггерами. Нужно сделать движение модели, похожее на движения змеи, т.е. чтобы модель следовала за поворотом родительского GameObject (сперва голова, затем тело, затем хвост). Из скрипта управлять Tramsform'ом не получается, т.к. объект заанимирован. Пробовал Animation Rigging, но у модели довольно кривой скелет, из за чего её попросту "скручивает". Возможно, есть ещё какие-то способы?

Туториал по змейке, возможно, вам поможет?)

Ну или вот
